# Pass iterator by reference to std::inner_product

Tags: c++, c++11

consider the following scenario:

```
std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> b {1, 2, 3, 4};
auto it = b.begin();
auto res = std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), it, 0); (*)
```

Is there a way to pass `it` to `std::inner_product` such that after (*) finish execution `it` will point to 4. (i.e. `*it == 4`) ?

Comment: `std::advance(it, a.size()); if (it != b.end()) {    std::cout << *it << "\n"; }`  How about this ?

Comment: @AlrjandroFreeman: given T.C. is correct about my suggestion having undefined behaviour under the Standard, please unaccept it so I can delete it - the concision "benefit" over Mohit's answer isn't worth flirting with undefined behaviour for....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mohit Jain says, there's no Standard-guaranteed portable way to do this, as you have to assume the `inner_product` implemenation happens to leave `it` where you want it, but you don't need to write a separate wrapper class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b {1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto it = b.begin();
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator ci;
    auto res = std::inner_product<ci,ci&,int>(a.begin(), a.end(), it, 0);
    std::cout << (void*)&*b.begin() << ' ' << (void*)&*it << '\n';
}
```

([Here](http://ideone.com/2Rfqvq) on ideone.com)

Comment: This is UB. A reference type isn't a valid `Iterator`, because it is not `Destructible`.

Comment: @T.C. why isn't it Destructible? Table 24 (17.6.3.1) says that Destrucible required that if `u` is the iterator, then the expression `u.~T()` has the post-condition that "All resources owned by u are reclaimed, no exception is propagated", where "T is an object or reference type to be supplied by a C++ program instantiating a template". I'm not sure what `u` is deemed to own, so it's unclear to me how to interpret that.  The trait `std::is_destructible<T>::value` is required by Table 49 to be true for all reference types.

Comment: If `T` is a reference type, `u.~T()` is ill-formed.

Comment: @T.C. I've spent five minutes looking for something in the Standard to support that, but nothing yet.  Will look again later....  Cheers.

Comment: @T.C. In meta.unary.prop: "For reference types, `is_destructible<T>::value` is true." So why not `Destructible`?

Comment: It doesn't prove anything of course, but as a bit of a sanity check on whether they rejected the code, I found GCC 4.9.2 and VS2013 *ostensibly* fine with invoking destructors via references.  Still haven't had time to dig deeper in the Standard.

Comment: @TonyD I haven't tried VS2013, but [GCC is not "fine"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26dab32c98e395ac). See [basic.lookup.classref]/p3.

Comment: @T.C.: your example code is flawed... if you explicitly invoke the destructor, you're still required to placement new an alternative object over the destructed object before execution leaves the scope.

Comment: @T.C. [here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1afa90ab9d754b0d) an example....

Comment: No, in your example, `T` is not a reference type any more.

Comment: @T.C. ahhh... I see your objection now... equivalent [to this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2fb004ecb39c670) in terms of the `inner_product` usage. Sorry for being slow to follow. Moves us to the next question - if the implementation happens to actually attempt such destruction (hard to imagine for `inner_product` specifically), then yes it would fail but as you say it's ill-formed so it's a compiler error not undefined behaviour, so is it safe if it compiles?  I have an vague memory of Standard clauses that might say not, but would have to dig again... :-(.

Comment: @TonyD No, instantiating a standard library template with a type that doesn't satisfy the requirements is just UB. (A hypothetical implementation might for instance detect this with expression SFINAE or plain old `std::is_reference` and send you an email with a link to [STL's talk on why explicit template arguments are usually a bad idea](https://youtu.be/AKtHxKJRwp4?t=48m45s) ;))

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `std::inner_product` implementation increments the second iterator in linear fashion, you can write a wrapper class of `std::vector<int>::iterator` which can be passed to `std::inner_product` and this wrapper (which updates iterator) indirectly will point to a new location.

But this way is strongly discouraged because:

1. You are making an assumption about the implementation.
2. There are much better ways to increment the iterator.
   `std::advance(it, a.size());` for example which should be preferred
   for your case.